# NSUserDefault Error. Int is appearing as a string when called

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I am working on an app that involves the use of NSUserDefaults. I have successfully saved two strings and am currently trying to save an int.

This is the code

```
var number = Int(0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

let numberOne = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    numberOne.setValue(number, forKey: "num")

let numberTwo = numberOne.stringForKey("num")

if numberTwo > 1
    {
       //will insert code later
    }
```

my error is that numberTwo is appearing as a string. This is my first time experimenting with NSUserDefault so, I am a novice but, any help is appreciated.

Comment: it seems you are asking for the string representation, thus you get it: stringForKey

Comment: because you ask string so it give you string with `stringForKey`

Comment: You are comparing apples (`String`) with oranges (`Int`) and never use `setValue:forKey` with user defaults.

Comment: So the code should be `intForKey`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of you want to treat it as an integer value, you should set (saving) and get the value as an integer, by using [setInteger:forKey:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1413614-setinteger?language=objc) and [integerForKey:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1407405-integerforkey):

```
var number = Int(0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let numberOne = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    numberOne.setInteger(number, forKey: "num")

    let numberTwo = numberOne.integerForKey("num") // 0

    if numberTwo > 1
    {
        //will insert code later
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your value is an `Int` you can retrieve it with (Swift 3)

```
let numberTwo = numberOne.integer(forKey: "num")
```

If Swift 2 I believe it was

```
let numberTwo = numberOne.integerForKey("num")
```

You can take a look at the [UserDefaults API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults) for more details and more options (such as `object(forKey:)`, `string(forKey:)`...)